# complex sql query (GROUP BY)

Tags: mysql, sql

I need some help building a query.

Here is what I need :

I have a table called **data**:

```
   ID| PRODUCT | VALUE |COUNTRY|  DEVICE | SYSTEM 
-----+---------+-------+-------+---------+--------
48   |    p1   |  0.4  |   US  |  dev1   | system1   
47   |    p2   |  0.67 |   IT  |  dev2   | system2   
46   |    p3   |  1.2  |   GB  |  dev3   | system3          
45   |    p1   |  0.9  |   ES  |  dev4   | system4   
44   |    p1   |  0.6  |   ES  |  dev4   | system1
```

I need to show which products have produced the most revenue and which country, device and system contributed the most.

**for example : the result i would get from the table would be:

```
 PRODUCT | TOTAL COST |COUNTRY|  DEVICE | SYSTEM 
  -------+------------+-------+---------+--------
    p1   |     1.9    |   ES  |  dev4   | system1   
    p2   |     0.67   |   IT  |  dev2   | system2   
    p3   |     1.2    |   GB  |  dev3   | system3
```

Top country is ES because ES contributed with 0.9 + 0.6 = 1.5 > 0.4 (contribution of US).

same logic for top device and top system.**

I guess for total revenue and product something like this will do :

```
SELECT SUM(value) as total_revenue,product FROM data GROUP BY product
```

But how can I add country,device and system?

Is this even feasible in a single query, if not what is the best way (performance wise) to do it?

Many thanks for your help.

**EDIT**
I edited the sample table to explain better.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need to do it in a single query?

Comment: your question is unclear: the way I understand it is that you want the  product that produced the most revenue but also, WITHIN this given product, which is the proportion of each country/device/system. ¿Is that so?

Comment: Hi, please check my edit, i think it's more clear now.

Answer (score 1):

Do it in separate queries:

```
SELECT   product,
         SUM(value) AS amount
FROM     data
GROUP BY country    -- change to device, system, etc. as required
ORDER BY amount DESC
LIMIT    1
```

Answer (score 1):

You are correct... it is not just a simple query... but 3 queries wrapped into one result.

I've posted my sample out on [SQL Fiddle here...](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/86bfd/9)

First query -- the inner most.  You need to get all revenue based on a per product/country and sort that by the product and DESCENDING on the total revenue to have highest revenue in first position per product.

Next query (where I've implemented use of MySQL @variable use). Since the first result order already has it in order of product and revenue rank, I set the rank to 1 every time a product changes from whatever the "@LastProd" is...  This would create ES = Rank #1 for product 1, then US = Rank #2 for product 1, then continue on the other "products".

The final outermost query re-joins back to the raw Data table but gets a list of all the devices and systems that comprised the product sale in question, but ONLY where the product rank was #1.

```
select
      pqRank.product,
      pqRank.country,
      pqRank.revenue,
      group_concat( distinct d2.device ) as PartDevices,
      group_concat( distinct d2.system ) as PartSystems
   from
      ( select
              pq.product,
              pq.country,
              pq.revenue,
              @RevenueRank := if( @LastProd = pq.product, @RevenueRank +1, 1 ) as ProdRank,
              @LastProd := pq.product
           from
              ( select 
                      d.product,
                      d.country,
                      sum( d.value ) as Revenue
                   from
                      data d
                   group by 
                      d.product,
                      d.country
                   order by
                      d.product,
                      Revenue desc ) pq,
              ( select @RevenueRank := 0,
                       @LastProd := ' ') as sqlvars
      ) pqRank
         JOIN data d2
            on pqRank.product = d2.product
           and pqRank.country = d2.country
   where
      pqRank.ProdRank = 1
   group by
      pqRank.product,
      pqRank.country
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do sth like that

```
CREATE TABLE data 
(
id int auto_increment primary key, 
product varchar(20), 
country varchar(4),
device varchar(20),
system varchar(20),
value decimal(5,2)
);

INSERT INTO data (product, country, device, system, value)
VALUES 
('p1', 'US', 'dev1', 'system1', 0.4), 
('p2', 'IT', 'dev2', 'system2', 0.67), 
('p1', 'IT', 'dev1', 'system2', 0.23);

select 'p' as grouping_type, product, sum(value) as sumval
from data
group by product
union all
select 'c' as grouping_type, country, sum(value) as sumval
from data
group by country
union all
select 'd' as grouping_type, device, sum(value) as sumval
from data
group by device
union all
select 's' as grouping_type, system, sum(value) as sumval
from data
group by system
order by grouping_type, sumval
```

It's ugly, I wouldn't use it, but it should work.

Comment: That doesn't look like what's being asked for.  Group by multiple fields will give the sum for each combination of those fields e.g. sum for each product X country, not the sum for each product and sum for each country.

Comment: Any particular reason that you're using `UNION` and not `UNION ALL`?